# Filling ViewBag from database returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm building a registering form for new members. Each member has a role (administrator or simple user). I'm trying to populate a DropDownList from my database and this is what I'm doing in my controller :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            ViewBag.Roles = context.Roles.ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

However, I'm getting a NullReferenceException error and I don't clearly see why. My Roles table has records so I don't know why this is returning a null exception.

Comment: What is context initialized to be?

Comment: Absolutly stupid from me, I forgot to initialize the context... Thank you ! Could you please post it as an answer and I'll accept it !

Comment: [Why not use the `M` in `MVC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is all of the code, then it's very likely that context is not initialized.  You probably want something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        ViewBag.Roles = context.Roles.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```